# How to display bars next to each other

Tags: highcharts

**Problem**

When I have only 1 series to show with multiple users in highcharts bar graph it display on top of each other instead of next to each other. Below is the code am using. Please guide me in the right direction.

Also if I add 1 more date in any user's series it shows up properly but that is not the solution as I will always have 1 date on my graph.

JS fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/bhats1989/b33mN/3/

**Code**

```
$(function () {
                           $('#team_container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar',
                    //inverted: true,
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    zoomType: 'xy',
                    events: {
                    },
                    zIndex: 5
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Team Activity Game',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                     text: 'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in and scroll',
                     x: -25 //center
                 },
                xAxis: {
                  title: {
                       text: 'Week Ending'
                      },
                    type: 'datetime',
                    maxZoom: 24 * 3600000, // Two days
                    labels: {
                         rotation: -45,
                         align: 'right',
                         formatter: function() {
                           return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%m/%Y', this.value);
                         }
                     },
                    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        events: {
                          legendItemClick: function(event) {
                            if (!this.visible)
                                return true;

                            var seriesIndex = this.index;
                            var series = this.chart.series;
                            var j = series.length;
                            for (var i = 0; i < series.length; i++)
                            {
                                if (series[i].index != seriesIndex)
                                {
                                  series[i].visible ? series[i].hide() : series[i].show();
                                  series[j-1].hide();
                                } 
                            }

                            return false;
                          }
                        }
                    }
                  },
                yAxis: {
                plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
                    color: '#f4e3e7',
                    from: 0,
                    to: 15,
                    events: {
                        mouseover: function(e) {                            
                           team_tooltipUpdate();
                        }
                    },
                    zIndex: 3
                  }],
                   gridLineColor: null,
                  title: {
                      text: 'Distance (kms)'
                     },
                     plotLines: [{
                     color: '#FF0000',
                     width: 2,
                     value: 15                  }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: team_myFormatter
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: [
                                                 {
                         name: 'Mark',
                         data: []
                         },                                              {
                         name: 'Joe',
                         data: [[Date.parse('7/28/2013 UTC'), 7.2954706108315 ]]
                         },                                              {
                         name: 'Max',
                         data: [[Date.parse('7/28/2013 UTC'), 25.668099736872 ]]
                         },                                              {
                         name: 'John',
                         data: [[Date.parse('7/28/2013 UTC'), 16.576099736872 ]]
                         }                                               ,{
                        name: 'yellowline',
                        visible: false,
                        showInLegend: false,
                        data: []
                         }

                    ]
               });

                          });
            function team_tooltipUpdate(){          
              var chart = $('#team_container').highcharts();
              chart.tooltip.refresh(chart.series[4].points[0]);     
            }
            function team_myFormatter(){
                var game_parameter = 'running';

                if(this.series.name == 'yellowline'){
                   return '<span style="color:Red;"><b>Danger Area</b></div>';
                }else{
                    if(game_parameter == 'running'){
                        return '<span style="color:'+ this.series.color + '"><b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%d\/%m\/%Y', this.x) +': '+ parseFloat(this.y).toFixed(2) +' kms</span>';
                    }else if(game_parameter == 'steps'){
                        return '<span style="color:'+ this.series.color + '"><b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%d\/%m\/%Y', this.x) +', No. of Steps: '+ parseFloat(this.y).toFixed(2) +'</span>';
                    }else if(game_parameter == 'floors'){
                        return '<span style="color:'+ this.series.color + '"><b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%d\/%m\/%Y', this.x) +', No. of Floors: '+ parseFloat(this.y).toFixed(2) +'</span>';
                    }else if(game_parameter == 'cycling'){
                        return '<span style="color:'+ this.series.color + '"><b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%d\/%m\/%Y', this.x) +': '+ parseFloat(this.y).toFixed(2) +' kms</span>';
                    }else if(game_parameter == 'heartrate'){
                        return '<span style="color:'+ this.series.color + '"><b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%d\/%m\/%Y', this.x) +': '+ parseFloat(this.y).toFixed(2) +' BPM</span>';
                    }                
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your `pointRange` option for series.

> **pointRange :** On linear and *datetime* axes, the range will be computed as the distance between the two closest data points.

As there is only one point, Highchart won't be able to calculate the `pointRange`...

To be sure that it will work, put it at the `tickInterval` value.

```
// ...
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // tickInterval has the same value
        // ...
    },
    // ...
},
// ...
```

For your question about First and Last label :

```
xAxis: {
    // ...                    
    showFirstLabel: false,
    showLastLabel: false,
    // ...
}
```

Look at this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b33mN/9/).

Comment: sorry mate didn't saw the link there.. yes that's perfect thanks alot !! I see you mentioned **showFirstLabel: false, showLastLabel: false,**

Comment: sorry for disturbing you. Can you please look at the following [link](http://jsfiddle.net/bhats1989/yM5d2/1/). I am passing only following dates **7/14/2013, 7/21/2013, 7/28/2013** but it's showing other dates as well. Do you know the reason why ?? Sorry for wasting your time, it's just am not getting a pointer in terms of what I should be doing here.

Comment: @colourtheweb Look at the update : http://jsfiddle.net/yM5d2/2/. I use the tickInterval and set it for a week and start the week to sunday.

Comment: Cool!! can't express how happy I am, you made my day :-) thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that with one point Highcharts won't be able to calculate pointRange for any of series. In that case set directly `pointRange` for series, see: http://jsfiddle.net/b33mN/5/

In the example, pointRange = tickInterval, it's probably you want to achieve.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, that did help but as you can see now on Y-axis there are 3 dates coming up but I only want to show **28/07/2013** and not **27/07/2013, 28/07/2013, 29/07/2013**. Can you plz suggest me what should I do for that.

Comment: @colourtheweb Look at my example, I removed the labels... there is some options to do that...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late but helpful answer, I use **pointPlacement** attribute of the config when using **column charts** and here is a plunker that shows how to use it to make columns stay next to each other .Results: http://plnkr.co/edit/uqZ4LEugMefLD6WSzHZT?p=preview

```
$(function () {
    $('#container2').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            categories:["Population","Kokulation"]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0,
                pointWidth:20
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Population',
            data: [
                ['Shanghai', 23.7],
                ['Lagos', 16.1]
            ],
            pointPlacement:0.23
        },
        {name:"Kokulation",
        data:[ 
                        ['Istanbul', 14.2],
                ['Karachi', 14.0]
             ],
             pointPlacement:-0.2146
        }
        ]
    });
});
```